# What am I supposed to do here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I keep trying to run this function, but the program keeps saying I need to enter in a float at the 6th line below. When I try to enter a float() function, it still says I need a float. I think I'm doing it wrong. How do I properly enter in a float? (I'm running Python 3.3.)

```
import math

a=input('a=?')

b=input('b=?')

c=input('c=?')

d=input('d=?')

critical_point_p=((-2*b)+math.sqrt((4*(math.pow(b, 2)))-(12*a*c)))/(2*a)

critical_point_n=((-2*b)-math.sqrt((4*(math.pow(b, 2)))-(12*a*c)))/(2*a)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the input() function, it grabs a STRING from the user.  So in essence, you're plugging in a string to the function.  The string could be 'hello', '5', or '5.23', they will all cause an error because it's reading as characters. You need to cast the input as a float.

```
a = float(input('a=?'))
```

That line will do the trick.  Of course, do the same for the other input fields.